# Play count and ratings in iTunes transferred to Music in 10.15?

Tags: itunes, music, catalina

Will the play count and ratings move from iTunes to Music in the update to 10.15?

Answer (score 1):

I have gotten confirmation that yes ratings and play counts both transfer to OS 10.15. I was asked for the source of my information: I checked with Joe Kissell the publisher of the Mac Take Control books and he check and confirmed with Kirk McElhearn the author of Take Control of Mac OS Media Apps. Both said in emails that both the play count and rating stars were preserved when up grading to OS 10.15

Answer (score 0):

When I updated from Mojave to Catalina, I noticed play counts were zero but ratings were unaffected. It looks like this could be because I am not subscribed to Apple Music, whereby the option to Use Listening History is unavailable to me..

> Select so that the music you listen to:
>
> - Is seen by your followers on Apple Music.
> - Influences the recommendations you get in For You in Apple Music.
>
> Note: This option appears if you’re signed in as a subscriber to Apple Music or iTunes Match.

Source: [Change Playback preferences in Music on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/music/musdf855a1b/1.0/mac/10.15)

If you are subscribed to Apple Music or iTunes Match, you can enable Use Listening History.

### To turn on Use Listening History on iOS 13:

1. Open the Settings app
2. Scroll down to Music
3. Tap Use Listening History

### To turn on Use Listening History on macOS Catalina:

1. Open Music app
2. Click Music from the menu bar and choose Preferences
3. Choose the Playback preferences pane
4. Check Listening History